# Can I make an object property type dependent of another property type?

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I have an object that looks like this:

```
interface AuthState {
  isSignedIn: boolean
  token?: string
  user?: User
}
```

`user` can be undefined, but only if `isSignedIn === false`. In the application it is impossible to have `isSignedIn === true` and no user object. I'd like to be able to enforce that and avoid having to do the following:

```
// If I don't check for `user`, TS will throw an error since it doesn't see any
// relation between the 2 properties
const userName = isSignedIn && user && user.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, this should be what you're looking for.

```
interface FalseAuthState {
  isSignedIn: false;
}

interface TrueAuthState {
  isSignedIn: true;
  token: string;
  user: User;
}

type AuthState = FalseAuthState | TrueAuthState;
```

So now, if you were to have an object like

```
// This does not throw an error because Typescript knows it's correct
const noAuth: AuthState = {
   isAuth: false
} 

// This will throw an error because Typescript demands a User and Token.
const yesAuth: AuthState = {
   isAuth: true
} 

// This will not throw an error.
const realAuth: AuthState = {
  isAuth: true,
  token: "ABCD123",
  user: new User()
} 

function printUser(auth: AuthState) {
  if (auth.isAuth) {
     console.log(auth.user); // Typescript knows there's supposed to be a user so there is no error
  }
}

function badPrintUser(auth: AuthState) {
   if (auth.isAuth === false) {
      console.log(auth.user); // Typescript will throw an error because there's no supposed to be a user here.
   }
}
```

In your example, the way you'd check is like so:

```
const userName = auth.isSignedIn && auth.user.name
```

or

```
const userName = auth.isSignedIn ? auth.user.name : undefined;
```

Unfortunately, you won't be able to remove the attributes from the object itself and use this to your advantage.  If you were to do this

```
const { isSignedIn, user } = (auth as TrueAuthState);
const userName = isSignedIn && user && user.name; // You still have to do this unless you really sure that the auth is a TrueAuthState
```